# I tried using Nokicert for my s40 phone but when i open it in cmd it gives me an Exception error

Tags: java, exception

I was trying to download certificates for my nokia s40 phone in Vista. but when i tried opening the cmd file, it gives me this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no swt-win32-3555 or
    swt-win32 in swt.library.path, java.library.path or the jar file
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.Library.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.C.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at net.tuxed.nokicert.NokiCertGUI.main(Unknown Source)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

That means that NokiCert cannot find the platform specific Win32 parts of `The Standard Widget Toolkit`.

I'm unsure how you've installed NokiCert or if you compiled it yourself somehow, but a good idea would probably be to [download the SWT installer for your platform here](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) and install it separately. That *should* set up the paths to the platform specific libraries so that they can be found correctly.

Comment: Thanks Joachim.
Actually, I read the procedure of downloading the certificates from a site [link] http://ionwap.wapka.mobi/site_24.xhtml
I have downloaded the widget and that error is resolved. Thanks for that.
I hope the rest will work. I'll try it and revert back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Hello. I have downloaded bluecove.2.1.0 and still it shows me an error "Native library intelbth not available. Native library bluecove not available." 
What can I do?

Comment: BlueCove requires a native bluetooth stack (ie a driver for the bluetooth chip) out of a few options listed [at their site](http://bluecove.org/). Do you have bluetooth working without BlueCove?

Comment: Yes Mr. Joachim. I do have all the required BlueCove additionals. But all my week's hard-work is fruitless as, sadly,I have come to know that BlueCove does not support Toshiba Bluetooth Stack. And I dont really know what else can be done.
Thanks a lot for your help though!